# jsonSlurper: get one value based on other value

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON response given below

```
[
    {
        "level3": "level3Value1",
        "level4": "level4value1"
    }, 
    {
        "level3": "level3Value2",
        "level4": "level4value2"
    },
    {
        "level3": "level3Value3",
        "level4": "level4value3"
    },
    {
        "level3": "level3Value4",
        "level4": "level4value4"
    },
    {
        "level3": "level3Value5",
        "level4": "level4value5"
    }
]
```

I need to select `level4value` based on `level3value` using JsonSlurper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `find` to get the list element containining your desired key/value pair

```
println([["level3": "level3Value3", "level4": "level4value3"],
         ["level3": "level3Value4", "level4": "level4value4"],
        ].find{ it.level4=='level4value4' }.level3)
```